# Need help editing FSTAB and making my new HDD a system wide mount

Tags: fstab

Okay so long story short. I'm trying to set up my Ubuntu 14.04 Server as a time machine backup. I bought a WD RED HDD to use as the HDD where the back ups save. I can see my Ubuntu PC in the list of time machine back up locations but when I try to connect to it, it says "OSSTATUS error 2" after researching the error is happening most likely because my WD RED drive doesn't have the right permissions and its location right now is /media/server and I believe it should be /mnt/server if its a system wide mount. I tried going into the disks application but when I click on the wheel "edit mount options"is faded and I cant click on it. It also says "2.0tb unknown" where the partitions are suppose to be.

I've read a few guides but I don't understand how to edit the FSTAB file I'm a n00b can somebody guide me through it?

The output for `cat /etc/fstab; echo; mount; echo; ls -l /media/server` is below...the drive I need to make a system wide mount is /dev/sda5

/etc/fstab: static file system information.

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB /media/timemachine/server ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0 
UUID=47e3c635-9838-4c1c-bb00-7954752f87ff none swap sw 0 0 
/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

**`mount`**

```
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096) 
/dev/sda5 on /media/timemachine/server type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096) 
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd) 
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1002/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=timemachine) 
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

**`ls -1 /media/server`**

```
ls: cannot access /media/server: No such file or directory
```

**`cat /etc/fstab`**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.  
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  

#Entry for /dev/sda6 :  
UUID=494aac22-8d5f-44eb-9483-04126a4d4b5e   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1  
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :  
UUID=949CA48C9CA46A86   /media/FACTORY_IMAGE    ntfs-3g     defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0  
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :  
UUID=B82ECEF22ECEA8A8   /media/HP   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 00  
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :  
UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB   /media/timemachine/server   ntfs-3g     defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0  
UUID=47e3c635-9838-4c1c-bb00-7954752f87ff   none    swap    sw  0   0  
/dev/fd0    /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8    0   0
```

**`ls -l /media/timemachine/server`**

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 17:57 TimeMachine
```

Comment: Please take some time to [format your post](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help). I can't because you didn't even take the time to copy the line breaks in properly and I can't tell what is a line and what isn't. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I deleted the information from the other drives that was posted sda5 is the only one that matters. Is that better? @Seth

Comment: I do NOT know what to do with the rest of the information. Please post the file as you actually see it with `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @michealb No not really, we need formatting to really read it (like what Luis did). As he said though, the line breaks were mangled so we can't really tell where to go from there.

Comment: OKay I added the info from the fstab file and I also left two spaces after each line for line breaks hopefully its not all mangled. @Luis

Comment: I reformatted it a little for you, to give you an idea of what we're talking about.  But there was some missing info at start of `mount` output, and repeated information above that.

Comment: Please enter commands one at a time to help keep yourself from getting more confused.  Also, the server is mounted at `/media/timemachine/server`, not `/media/server`, so try `ls -l /media/server` instead.

Comment: Thank you. What is the code to paste text in that little box?  Also when I try ls -1 /media/server it says "no such file or directory found". @MartyFried

Comment: The first comment from @seth had the link, and at the top of that link's page is your answer.  Hint, watch the formatted output below your post as you make changes; it will show the result.

Comment: Thanks. So what do I do next since ls -l /media/server isn't returning any results. @MartyFried

Comment: Sorry, I pasted without looking. :-(  I meant to say try `ls -l /media/timemachine/server` instead.  That is where it is being mounted (see output of mount command, or fstab's directive).

Comment: Okay I posted the output at the end. The formatting page says to indent 4 spaces to create that box thing I tried but it didn't work. @MartyFried

Comment: Seems like it worked. Apparently, there is nothing in the root directory of the WD drive except a sub-directory; `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  2 17:57 TimeMachine` means there is a directory (the very first character 'd').  But, it is owned by root, so that will need to be changed, either by mount options and/or by changing the owner of `/media/timemachine/server` using the `chown` command.

Comment: I did a google search should is this the chown command I should be using?   sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /media/mynewdrive.  Who/What should I change the owner of the folder to?  Just to be clear I should input the command as sudo chown -R timemachine:timemachine /media/timemachine/server? @MartyFried

Comment: If only you use the system, use your login name for both user and group (instead of "timemachine:timemachine").

Comment: Okay I did it but didn't get a confirmation or anything. Just to confirm I did sudo chown -R admin:admin /media/timemachine/server (my main acct name is admin, timemachine is my other user acct I had to set up according to the instructions when I was setting up time machine. What should I do next? @MartyFried

Answer (score 1):

This is getting too involved for comments.  But so far, there's not enough information to give a complete answer.  I have not had experience with permanently mounting USB drives, but I am assuming they are the same, if they do not get removed.  However, I also think that since there is a possibility that they might not be connected, that has to be considered, as you don't want your system to fail to boot due to this possibility.

Normally, a USB or other removable drive gets mounted automatically in the `/media/username/x` directory, where x is the label or UUID of the drive.  This appears to be what is happening with your drive, but it's hard to tell as you are not providing needed information.  You need to pay more attention, and be a little more resourceful.  For example, you still have not said whether any data is available anywhere in the `/media/timemachine/server/TimeMachine` directory.  And it would be nice to see the directory to see if the files are owned by root, which I am only guessing is the case.  If this is the case, then that is the problem that must be addressed.

But, if you don't see the files at all, then there is another problem.  But since there is a directory, I'm guessing the files are there, and are mounted.

There is a lot of information on [Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) and also [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) that you should look at.  It seems to say that, for NTFS drives, you should enter this in `/etc/fstab`:
`UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB /media/timemachine/server ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0`
But I'm not sure how to handle a drive that's not available at boot time (I think you would have the option to continue, but I'm not sure).

Another option is to use `mount` or `pmount`, and possibly run it as a startup task.

Sorry I can't give absolute answers, but if you can provide concrete, useful information, I can probably help you work out the problems.  I just don't have any experience with external USB NTFS drives.

**Edit - reply to first two comments from OP**

OK, sorry about the USB assumption.  Is it more or less permanently connected?

I'm not sure if it's automatically mounted or not. The way I would tell would be to disable the line in `/etc/fstab`, and reboot to see if it shows up as mounted.  If it does, I don't know if it will need to be disabled or not; I'd probably not worry about it yet.

I believe I misled you about changing the permissions of the directory.  I did a little reading, and NTFS does not support file ownership/permissions like linux, so they are set by the mount options (at the time of mounting).  So, the entry in `/etc/fstab` is important.

If you want to make sure that your entry is the one being used, you could change the mountpoint to `/mnt/timemachine` (or anything else you prefer).  The name is not important.  What will happen is that the specified directory will become the root directory of your mounted drive, so in this case, I believe it may become `/mnt/timemachine/TM`.  Once mounted, it is like any other directory.

If you do this, you *must* create the mountpoint before trying to mount it.
`sudo mkdir /mnt/timemachine`; then change `/etc/fstab` from the previous line:

```
UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB   /media/timemachine/server   ntfs-3g     defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
```

to this:

```
UUID=1B9C57F11BBEC3DB /mnt/timemachine ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

**Now what?**
Next, you can check the permissions.  Issue the command `ls -l /mnt/timemachine`.

The first set of 10 characters of the output is the permissions; the first column is type, like 'd' for directory, or 'l' for link.  Then there are 3 sets of 3 columns, for permissions:
`User Group Everyone`
 `RWX  RWX   RWX` for Read/Write/Execute.  So, if you see `drwxrwxrwx`, that means everyone can read or write to it. `drwxr-xr-x` means only the owner can write, but everyone else can read.  The execute bit for a directory allows you to see the directory.

Next, is the number of entries in the directories, then the owner and group.  If it says `root  root`, then unless it also has `drwxrwxrwx` permissions, you can't write to it.  I think you probably don't care about the owner so much as the permissions, unless you want to do some extra configuration which I can't help with.

Comment: Okay sorry I will provide complete information here. 1) The drive is not a USB flashdrive its an actual HDD plugged into a sata port.  2) The location of the drive is /media/timemachine/server so yes it is being automatically mounted. 3) Theres no data on the drive just 1 folder called "TM" where the timemachine back ups are suppose to save too but nothing is in the folder since my macbook cannot connect to it.  4) How do I find out if its owned by root? @MartyFried

Comment: For #2) I'm not actually sure if its being automatically mounted. How would I find out? Also just to be clear what I need is for the HDD to be a system wide mount and not a user specific mount. I believe since its /media/timemachine/server and "timemachine" is the name of a user account on the computer and "server" is what I named the HDD it is a user specific mount right now. @MartyFried

Comment: @michealb - See edits in my answer.  Also, FYI, if you are replying to a post made by me, you don't need to add my name.  I needed to add it for you, because you are not the one who made the post.